# What is the best way to add a progressbar to the whole Angular 4 Web Application?

Tags: angular, progress-bar, angular-material2

Kindly let me know which is the most optimal way to add a progressbar to the whole Angular 4 Web Application using MdProgressBar of Angular Material 2.
I would like to add service which would load the progressbar template on every http request. Should I use the http interceptor concept to achieve this?

Comment: How exactly do you specify "best way" or "optimal way"? It's safe to assume that this is something entirely different for everyone.

Comment: I am new to angular, so unable to proceed further.I would like to add service  which would load the progressbar template on every http request. Should I use the http interceptor concept to achieve this?

Comment: You should add your last comment to your question directly. Without this additional information, the question is rather off-topic on SO. I don't know the answer because I haven't tried the new HttpClient that supports interceptors nor `MdProgressBar`.

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer